# Clarifying the use of Update() and FixedUpdate()? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, syntax, physics-engine

So I understand that FixedUpdate should be used for physics operations and such but I am having trouble understanding what counts as physics. So for example, I move my character by looking at what keys are pressed then I apply a force. Currently I am doing this in Update(). Should this functionality be moved to FixedUpdate() since addForce is code that's being applied to a physics object (the player, since it has a rigidbody component)?

But then, if I do move this code to fixedUpdate(), would it be fine to run the input.GetKey in that method? I read somewhere that inputs can get dropped if they're listened for in FixedUpdate()? So yeah, confusing...It almost sounds like Input.GetKey should be in Update() and when a key is pressed a flag is activated. Meanwhile, the functionality in FixedUpdate() is watching for the appropriate flag to be activated. And such...This way input is handled in Update() and movement is in FixedUpdate()...am I understanding this right?

Also, I am using colliders and triggers, would the code for these also be located in FixedUpdate()?

Comment: Colliders and triggers use events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most challenging things to understand without good resources. It is often the cause of most "beginner bugs" in new Unity developer's code.

### Before we start:

As you may have read in documentation, the following are understood.

Initialization order:

1. Awake
2. Start

Frame order:

3. Update
4. LateUpdate

You can further customize the order of specific scripts (ex: always run ScoreManager before PlayerMovement) by going to Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution Order.

**However**, this is not a complete list of what's going on in Unity. There are physics cycles, rendering, and input that all occur at different times in this order. The key thing to note is that there are 2 *script execution Cycles*. "Frame" (most commonly - Update), and a "Fixed" (most commonly - FixedUpdate).

Consider taking a cursory glance at the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

**What does it mean to have 2 script execution cycles?** Put simply, all MonoBehaviour methods are tied to one of these 2 cycles. These methods will only perform their logic once until the cycle is complete. In other words, your "PlayerMovement.cs" script's Update method will only run one time for every frame. Your OnCollissionStay will only run one time for every Fixed cycle.

### Why does Unity have 2 different cycles.

**Fixed Cycles** (FixedUpdate) in Unity are:

- deterministic
- math-based
- not dependent on rendering

Physics doesn't need to have sprites rendered or UI elements visible to be able to calculate if a collider has been hit or if gravity should be applied. Unity separates out the physics-specific data to perform calculations efficiently. Additionally, a lot of this is deterministic. If you started at (0,0) on one frame and your rigibody moved to (10,10) on the next frame (and you did not teleport), I can reasonably assume that you moved through point (5,5). This allows Unity's physics engine to "interpolate" collissions and interactions. This means that physics doesn't need to see every frame of "action" to determine if a collission has occurred. The fixed cycle allows Unity to calculate the physics separately from the frame and communicate those changes safely.

**Frame Cycles** (Update) in Unity are the basis of all Unity's interaction. Nothing can happen without a frame updating the game. There's no point in wasting CPU cycles calculating game logic if the frame isn't being updated. This means that:

- Inputs are tied to the frame
- Frame cycles are dependent on rendering

Something important to note: fixed cycles may or may not occur every frame. At lower framerates, multiple fixed cycles may occur each frame. At higher framerates, many frames will occur without any fixed cycles.

### What does it mean for my game logic?

For the most part, these 2 cycles work in harmony fairly well. The most common cause for concerns are the following:

- Trying to update a GameObjects position using Transform **and** physics (i.e. Rigidbody). You should try to only update a GameObjects position on one of the 2 cycles. If the GameObject is expected to collide with things or interact with physics like gravity, use Rigidbody.move or Rigidbody.velocity.
- Trying to read input in the Fixed cycle. Since the fixed cycle can occur 0-many times per frame, input may be missed. If you use GetButtonDown() on one frame but the FixedCycle doesn't run, you will "miss" that input in FixedUpdate. It's usually best to use bools or queues to manage this discrepancy between input and the physics system. (Like setting a bool jump = true in Update, and reading/updating the bool jump in FixedUpdate when you actually perform the physics component)