# Touch is slow when checking for touch area

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I've got a script called TouchDragDrop.cs which lets me touch and drag an object in 2D space.

The two functions I want to show are:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        // touchPosition = touch.position; 
        touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began: beginTouchMove();  break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved: moveTouch();  break;
            case TouchPhase.Stationary: stationaryTouch(); break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended: endTouchMove();  break;
        }

    }
}

private void moveTouch()
{
    //if ((myCollider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPosition)) && (isMoving))
    if(isMoving)
    {
        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2(touchPosition.x - deltaX, touchPosition.y - deltaY);
        //gameObject.transform.position = newPosition;
        myRigidbody2D.MovePosition(newPosition);
        //if(debuglog) Debug.Log("Touch Position:  x: " + touchPosition.x.ToString() + " y: " + touchPosition.y.ToString());
        //if(debuglog) Debug.Log("RigidBody: " + myRigidbody2D.position.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, to accurately move the object I need to make sure that the touch is on top of the object, so thats why I originally had the line:

`if ((myCollider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPosition)) && (isMoving))`

But this slows down the app so much that dragging is hard work, like I really have to press and drag slowly to get the character to move with me.  So if I take it out and just have `if(isMoving)` its fast again.

How can I make sure I'm dragging the object only and not just a bit of the screen?

Comment: Where are you defining isMoving?

Comment: How many objects have this script attached to them?

Comment: It gets defined in beginTouchMove to true, them set to false in endTouchMove. There are no more than 10 of these objects at one time, it starts with just one and three dressing is noticeably slow on just the one.

Comment: If you only have 1 object with the script attached, it's still incredibly slow?

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that you have many objects running this script, which is what is causing your issues. To verify this, try reducing the number of objects that have a **TouchDragDrop** component to 1 or 2 total objects. You will probably notice the game is no longer slow.

Every time your touch the screen, all objects with an attached **TouchDragDrop.cs** script are reading the input, and then performing their moveTouch logic. If you have 50 objects with **TouchDragDrop.cs** attached, you will perform Physics2D.OverlapPoint 50 times. This is what is likely killing your performance.

Physics2D.OverlapPoint should only be called once. If many objects need to respond to your touch, consider moving your Input and touch logic to a single gameObject that is only responsible for reading the input and returning which collider is hit. Then move your "movement logic" to a different script (perhaps called **Draggable.cs** Rather than doing a comparison on every single GameObject, you could then do the following from that single input script:

```
touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
Collider2D touchedCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPosition)
Draggable dragObj = touchedCollider?.GetComponent<Draggable>();
dragObj?.MoveTouch(touchPosition);
```

---

## Update

Since the issue is not related to the number of GameObjects at this time, it's likely due to contention between the Fixed cycle and the Frame cycle. I wrote a fairly long [explanation of the differences between the 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174208/clarifying-the-use-of-update-and-fixedupdate-unity2d/60175133#60175133), but in short I believe this may be your issue:

**When you read your input every frame while moving, your physics object's collider position doesn't Update immediately. It only updates on the Fixed cycle, which means that your input has a slight chance to have moved outside of the collider.**

Here's a new solution:

Rather than validate that you're touching the object every frame, let's assume that you only need to check the touch position once (during TouchPhase.Began). I recommend something like this:

```
void BeginTouchMove()
{
    if(myCollider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPosition))
    {
        isMoving = true;
    }
}
```

Then you can keep your MoveTouch() logic the same as you have above, with only checking (isMoving).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But when the game starts there's only one object with this script attached.

Comment: Well then your other problem is likely that you're continually updating your touch position in the update cycle, but the physics position isn't updating. Your framerate isn't dropping, is it? @Chud37

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the frame rate on android. This is like my second unity app lol!

Comment: @Chud37 I've updated my answer with some additional information.