# player stutters when moving unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

whenever the player uses its jetpack or when there's a lot of velocity, the player stutters. I tried using interpolate and other things like that but the only outcome was even more stutter. If anyone knows what the cause for the stuttering is, please tell me and if you want to, maybe even explain your answer :)

here is what i mean by the player stuttering :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6q3vvQtwjM

here is my player code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    //basic variables
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 5f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float Jumpforce = 5f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float JetPackForce = 5f;

    [SerializeField]
    public bool canUseJetpack = true;

    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    [SerializeField]
    private Animator animator;
  
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    //runs when game starts
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    //runs every frame
    void Update()
    {
        //applies force thus making player to move left or right
        var move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(move * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

        //changes player animation state
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

        //flip the player if facing right or left
        if (move < 0 && isFacingRight)
        {
            flip();
        }
        else if (move > 0 && !isFacingRight)
        {
            flip();
        }

        //checks if the space key is pressed and that the player velocity on the y axis is smaller than 0.001
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space") && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.001f)
        {
            //adds force from below the player thus making the player jump
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, Jumpforce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        //checks for the key 'Q' to be pressed and that there is enough fuel in the jetpack
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) && canUseJetpack == true) 
        {
            //ads force from below the player thus making the player fly using its jetpack
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * JetPackForce);
            //decreases the fuel in the jetpack
            JetpackBar.instance.UseFuel(0.1f);
            //makes the player run the using jetpack animation
            animator.SetBool("UsingJetpack", true);
        }
        else
        {
            //if the player isn't using the jetpack, switch to the idle animation or the run animation depending if the player is moving or not
            animator.SetBool("UsingJetpack", false);
        }

        //checks if the player health is less than 0
        if (HealthBar.instance.currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            //if so, restart the game
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }

    //checks if someting collided with the player
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        //if the thing collided with the player has a tag of 'Enemy'
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            //then, make the player take damage
            HealthBar.instance.takeDamage(25);
        }
    }

    //flip the player
    void flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Have you tried switching to `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update`? Doing physics in `Update()` can be wonky sometimes. Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174208/clarifying-the-use-of-update-and-fixedupdate-unity2d) for a really good breakdown of `FixedUpdate` vs `Update`.

Comment: i have tried to switch the update to the fixedupdate but that just made everything worse

Comment: Are you still using `Time.deltaTime` in `FixedUpdate`, or have you switched to using the more appropriate [`Time.fixedDelataTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

Comment: If `JetpackBar` regenerates fuel over time, try making it so the jetpack wont keep trying to fly while it's refueling. Alternatively make it so when the `JetpackBar` runs out of fuel the player must release the Jetpack key before the jetpack will work again. Either of these might prevent you from constantly regenerating jetpack fuel and using it instantly creating a stuttering effect.

Comment: should i use the Time.fixedDeltaTime anywhere else except the 3rd line in the fixedupdate? also no good results :(

Comment: @DekuDesu see [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) -> always use `Time.deltaTime` .. it has the correct value also within `FixedUpdate`. You want to get user Input always in `Update`, not in `FixedUpdate`, because you might miss an Input if you only check at certain steps between frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all whenever dealing with Rigidbodies you do not want to use the `Transform` component to move an object. You rather want to only move it via the `Rigidbody`/`Rigidbody2D` component!

Then there is a general issue. You can either move your object hard based on the input **or** use the physics and forces. Both at the same time is not possible because both `transform.position` or the actually "correct" [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) will overrule the forces so these two systems are clashing all the time.

Therefore I would rather simply overwrite the [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) directly like e.g.

```
void Update()
{
    // Store the current velocity
    var velocity = rb.velocity;

    var move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    // Only overwrite the X component
    // We don't need Time.deltaTime since a velocity already
    // moves the object over time
    velocity.x = move * speed;

    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

    if (move < 0 && isFacingRight)
    {
        flip();
    }
    else if (move > 0 && !isFacingRight)
    {
        flip();
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("space") && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.001f)
    {
        // simply overwrite the Y velocity
        // You'll have to adjust that value of course
        // and might want to rename it ;)
        velocity.y = Jumpforce;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) && canUseJetpack) 
    {
        // Here we want to use Time.deltaTime since the jetpack
        // shall increase the Y velocity over time
        // again you'll have to adjust/rename that value
        velocity.y += JetPackForce * Time.deltaTime;
        
        // Also adjust this value!
        // To be frame-rate independent you want to use Time.deltaTime here
        JetpackBar.instance.UseFuel(0.1f * Time.deltaTime);
      
        animator.SetBool("UsingJetpack", true);
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("UsingJetpack", false);
    }

    // After having calculated all changes in the velocity now set it again
    rb.velocity = velocity;

    if (HealthBar.instance.currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer but when you say to rename it, what do you mean by renaming 'it'? And why should I rename 'it'? Thanks again :D

Comment: Haha I only ment it is no longer a "force" so maybe `JumpForce` would rather be e.g. `JumpVelocity` and `JetPackForce` could e.g. rather be `JetPackAcceleration` or something like that ;)